# DLMS/COSEM in PHP

Tags: php, dlms

I'm creating a simple web based AMR (Automated Meter Reading) system, but can't find any implementations of [DLMS/COSEM](http://www.dlms.com/index2.php) in php, maybe someone has a solution?

DLMS/COSEM are communication standards (definitions, rules and methods) for meters

Comment: It might help a little if you gave some context to what DLMS/COSEM are?

Comment: Incase it doesn't get added: http://www.dlms.com/index2.php

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information around however a quick check on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLMS) leads to [this implementation](http://www.gurux.fi/index.php?q=GXDLMSCOSEM) which presumably is open source (at least the DLMS component). It might be native code or Java (I haven't checked it but they have some Java DLMS component in the list so who knwows). In either case you can make some kind PHP wrapper for it I guess or reimplement the protocol in PHP.